# Removing dot from subdomain using regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

This is the regEx to match url.

what I want is to remove dot (.) after the subdomain.

So if i enter `http://www.abc.xyz.def.com` I want subdomain to be `abc.xyz` but i am getting `abc.xyz.`

I want to do this with this regular expression only.

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?(([A-z0-9]+\.)*)([A-z0-9]+\.[A-z]{2,4})(\/(.)*)?(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$
```

Comment: What is `\?{0}` supposed to be for? What does it mean to match exactly 0 `?` characters?

Comment: Your regexp doesn't seem to match at all: https://regex101.com/r/tO5tN4/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tO5tN4/3     this is matching

Comment: Barmar you have added extra space at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is OK to require at least 2 characters in the subdomain name, you could proceed as follows: test for the point after the match group instead of at the end of it, and allow points inside the match group as long as they are not the first or last character of it:

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-z0-9][A-z0-9\.]+[A-z0-9])\.([A-z0-9]+\.[A-z]{2,4})(\/(.)*)?(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$
```

To also allow a 1-character subdomain, add ? to second part of the match group:

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-z0-9]([A-z0-9\.]+[A-z0-9])?)\.([A-z0-9]+\.[A-z]{2,4})(\/(.)*)?(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$
```

EDIT:

The point before the domain is now outside any group, so neither subdomain nor domain get it included.

Comment: It is not a good idea to use `[A-z]` in JS unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: but this add dot to the domain so the prob still arises, I can remove it with subString in js but i dont want to do that

Comment: @Saiyam, I updated the answer to take that into account

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.` from the capture group after `www.` to the next group. You can still match `.` in that group by putting it inside the `[]`, but it won't match at the end of the subdomain because that's matched in the next group (unless you have an invalid domain like `www.foo.bar..baz.com`).

```
^((https?):\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-z0-9.]+)*(\.[A-z0-9]+\.[A-z]{2,4})(\/(.)*)?(\/?\?{0}|\/?\?{1}.*)$\
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tO5tN4/4)